# How to change collider in individual tile in tilemap

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using tilemap in unity for level building. I need colliders on my tiles. If I add a tilemap collider to the tilemap it generates a collider around the tile, however I need to edit these colliders and have different colliders for every tile.

How could i do this?

**Wrong collider:**
[image]

**What i want to achieve:**
[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your case you have square tiles and the [Tilemap Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TilemapCollider2D.html) box fits it naturaly.

To edit the Tilemap Collider, go to the [Sprite Editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/Manual/SpritePhysicsShapeEditor.html) in the Sprite you're trying to use and modify how you want it to by clicking in [Custom Physics Shape](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CustomPhysicsShape.html)

[image: ![Sprite Editor]

Then, once you have the right shape, reset your Tilemap Collider and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you. I put tiles to same layer as player. I am using sort axis, but if player walk near to wall he is under the wall. But I think I can fix it by creating custom script that check all tiles and if tile has higher y the tile will be put to lower layer.

Answer (score 1):

Updated Answer for newer versions of Unity 2019+:

You now have to open the sprite sheet in the sprite editor and then select "Custom Physics Shape" under the Sprite Editor dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Sprites usually automatically generate a physics shape. You can use Unity's [physics shape editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/Manual/SpritePhysicsShapeEditor.html) to modify your sprites generated physics shape. With this, you could modify each tile's automatically generated shape. If you're looking for a more tailored shape that is more specific than just the sprite, you may need to build custom colliders that are not tied to your painted tilemap.

Answer (score -1):

I've discovered "PolygonCollider2D" which allows you to make a more precise collision shape. I've made the collisions as a separate Game object.

Comment: That's not a scalable solution if you're working with tilemaps as author of the question does